# Michelson interfreometer with removed mirror

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, interference

The beamsplitter in Michelson interferometer influenced the light, going through respectively being reflected by 90°.

[image]

[Image source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson_interferometer)

Has somebody of you ever see what shape has the spot from a laser source on the observation screen if one of the mirrors is not installed?

---

Edit: [There](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317051/michelson-interferometer-circular-fringes/317114?noredirect=1#comment713606_317114) is a comment:

> I have not and I no longer have access to a Michelson interferometer. If you have observed fringes then they might be due to the multiple reflections from the top and bottom of the beam splitter and the compensator.

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but if your asking which mirror will produce a spot on the screen if the other mirror is not present. The answer is both mirrors, A or B, will produce a spot on the screen if the other mirror is gone.

Comment: Lambda, I'm asking has one removed one of the two mirrors and what he -the **observer** - see on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have blocked the light from one of the mirrors. The image on the screen is simply the light from your laser projected onto the screen. The interference pattern goes away. The setup below produces the two images that you see. I have two beam splitters, one is just plate glass, because I wanted to show the image that returns to the laser too. If I block either mirror the interference patterns go away. I hope this helps.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I hoped to see from the metal lattice of the beam splitter fringes on the screen. Could you please increase the distance of the observer screen to the beam splitter to say 2 ... 3 meters?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Please make the distance from the beam splitter to the observed image bigger. In the best case to a distance of 2 or 3 meters. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show an image of the screen before and after blocking one mirror? Thanks

Comment: I don't have a pic of that, but they stay the same size and shape. They lose the interference pattern and lose some of their brightness. They essentially become pale reddish disks of light.

Comment: Lambda Thirst at all thank you so much. Now, the photo you've taken shows the two beam splitters with the laser point on them? What I hoped to see was the reflected from the beam splitter laser light at a distance say 2 or 3 meters away. If I refer to your first photo the observer screen has to be placed in the direction of the upper left corner of the photo. BTW, just curious, the first "beam splitter" is just a windows glass? The second is a coated half transparent glass?