# Michelson interferometer. Why is the path difference in the experimental setup $2d \cos \theta$ and not $2d/\cos \theta$?

Tags: optics, geometry, interferometry

[image]

All textbooks say that the path difference is $2d \cos \theta$. But in my mind, by constructing triangles, I seem to get $2d/\cos \theta$ and intuitively I thought as angle increases, the path difference should also increase. And when angle is $90°$, path difference should be infinite. Think something is fundamentally wrong with the way I am thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point here I think is that the path difference must be calculated at a wavefront, which is orthogonal to the rays.

See the diagram below and note that the path difference is $\ell_1 + \ell_2$ instead of $2\ell_1$.

$\ell_1 = \dfrac{d}{\cos\theta}$ indeed, but $\ell_2 = \ell_1 \cos(2\theta)$.

Therefore, $$\Delta = \ell_1 + \ell_2 = \left(1+\cos(2\theta)\right)\ell_1 = (1 + \cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta)\ell_1=2\cos^2\theta \;\ell_1 = 2d\cos\theta$$

[image: diagram of path difference]

The formed fringes are "fringes of equal inclination".

See

1. [Michelson interferometer circular fringes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317051/276458)
2. [Fringes of equal inclination (Haidinger fringes) Why is the interference pattern circular?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/478840/276458)

Note that here we assume the refractive index is universally $1$ (or at least uniform in the space), which is true for Michelson interferometer. For more general cases, e.g. thin film interference, the path difference is $2 n d\cos\theta$. See [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/interf.html) for the derivation.